# How to include AAR in Dynamic Feature Module?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, dynamic-feature-module

I want to put a big AAR library ("crypteriumsdk") into a Dynamic Feature Module, which can be installed on-demand. But when I do that, it can't find its resources (theme):

> resource style/CrypteriumTheme (aka
> com.crypter.cryptocyrrency:style/CrypteriumTheme) not found.

I also added `tools:replace="android:theme"` to `application` in main Manifest (app module).

What is wrong here?

[image]

[image]

`settings.gradle`:

```
include ':crypteriumsdk'
include ':wallet'
include ':app'
```

`wallet.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation project(":app")
    implementation project(':crypteriumsdk') // added the library here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Manifest gets merged too early for the actual theme implementation to be available on the user's device.

You can add this to your base module's styles.xml:

```
    <style name="CrypteriumTheme" />
```

This allows for the style resource id to be found at install time and for it to be overwritten once the module is available and launched.

See [this sample](https://github.com/android/plaid/blob/master/core/src/main/res/values/styles.xml#L74) for a working implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this works! 

Do you maybe know what I can do about resources with same name from 3rd party libraries? E.g. we use library A in our base (app) module, and then library B in dynamic feature module, and both libraries have some layout resource with same name. This causes error when trying to build a bundle: `Modules 'base' and 'dynamicfeature' contain entry 'res/layout/design_bottom_navigation_item.xml' with different content.`. 

I know it's offtopic for this question, but would highly appreciate your experience on this :)

Comment: Here is a question regarding this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702779/getting-this-error-modules-base-and-modulea-contain-entry-res-drawable-xyz

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up. I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702779/getting-this-error-modules-base-and-modulea-contain-entry-res-drawable-xyz/63451083#63451083) to the question.